# APP Engine listening to Port 3000 giving 502 Bad Gateway error

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I am new to node.js coding. I am learning to build a app I want to host on GCP App engine.
I have created a Node.js code which has hard requirement to listen to port 3000.

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const crypto = require('crypto');
const cookie = require('cookie');
const nonce = require('nonce')();
const querystring = require('querystring');
const request = require('request-promise');
const { Console } = require('console');
// const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const PORT = 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello App Engine!');
});
```

On Yaml file I have specifically added ports to forward.

```
network:
  forwarded_ports:
    - 3000/tcp
```

unless I dont use 8080 port, app engine is failing with 502 Bad Gateway.

Is there a way I can use Port 3000 in App engine.
It works if I change the Port to 8080. But I want this to be at 3000.

I created firewall rules

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1nPs.png)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you cannot change the default port in GAE.

The `forwarded_ports` is intended to open access to other services listening on other ports but always there should be something listening on the port 8080.

You can create a dummy service listening in port `8080` and possibly redirect to your app in port 3000. Something else to keep in mind is that when accessing the desired service in port 3000 or any other, this should be specified in the url like `https://PROJECT_ID.REGION_ID.r.appspot.com:3000` or more general `https://PROJECT_ID.REGION_ID.r.appspot.com:PORT`